# how to select the row where sum reach 1000?

Tags: mysql

```
id | amount
1  |   96
2  |   0.63
3  |   351.03
4  |   736
5  |   53
6  |   39
7  |   105
8  |   91
```

I want to get the row where sum(amount) reach 1000
please note only the row that trigger 1000

Comment: I only see one table

Comment: You're not making any sense

Comment: What does the second table do?

Comment: You should give us an example of the result you expect! your question is not very precise.    "reach 1000"  as in sum >= 1000? Starting from the first row (id = 1)?

Answer (score 0):

This query should do what (I think) you want:

```
select id, (select sum(amount) 
            from table1 t1 
            where t1.id <= table1.id) as total
from table1
having total >= 1000
limit 1
```

For your sample table, it gives

```
id  total
4   1183.66
```